# Honeypot detection: How is TCP/IP implemented on honeypots?

Tags: tcp, honeypot

I'm currently studying how to do honeypot detection and was wondering if a possible lead is to analyse how honeypots implement their TCP/IP protocol.

I've been looking through the source code for a number of the honeypots (e.g. Kippo) but haven't found where they implement this protocol. I'm not sure the honeypot has left it to the OS to run the TCP/IP, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong places.

Any advice is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: just curious, what do you think is the significance of implementing TCP/IP in honeypots?  My impression is that a honeypot should not differ in its TCP/IP settings from a regular system - the only difference would be the purpose of the system existing as well as some relaxation of security on the system so it effectively acts like a honeypot.

Comment: I was reading a book on Virtual Honeypots and within, it was mentioned that a previous version of Honeyd honeypot implemented the reassembling of fragmented IP packets incorrectly. (Honeyd forgot to compare the protocol number when reassembling fragmented packets)

Based on this, it made me wonder if there were any other honeypots that had similar "errors" in its implementation of TCP/IP. (if it implemented it at all)

Comment: If your question is basically asking if other software contains some bugs, the answer is probably yes but this question isn't very answerable from my perspective.  All software may contain bugs for various reasons and the fact that the software you're interested in is honeypot software doesn't influence this imho

Answer (score 2):

The comment about honeyd led me to find this paper:

https://www.merit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Honeyd_Detection.pdf

containing this bit of background information:

> In order to avoid being fingerprinted and identified based on the host operating system that it is running on, the Honeyd software interacts directly with the network. Therefore it is responsible for performing its own packet fragment reassembly, and does not rely on packet fragment operations of the host operating system.

So it sounds like this particular honeypot *does* have its own TCP/IP implementation, enabling it to mimic different operating systems with different vulnerabilities.

The operating system feature that makes it possible is "raw sockets", a privileged API that lets you send and receive packets at layer 2, bypassing the kernel implementation of IP and TCP.

Comment: Thanks Wumpus! This was helpful. I guess Honeyd is a bit of an exception right now in terms of implementing its own TCP/IP. Haven't found any other honey pot yet that does the same.

Answer (score 0):

> How is TCP/IP implemented on honeypots?

It isn't. Honeypots like Kippo use the host operating system's TCP/IP stack, just like a normal SSH server. You aren't going to be able to distinguish between them at a network level.

Comment: ok thanks. Saved me from going down a rabbit's hole there!